Debugging Windows VBS enclaves
I'm trying to debug a VBS enclave by following this Microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/trusted-execution/vbs-enclaves-dev-guide#step-4-debugging-vbs-enclaves:~:text=Step%204%3A%20Debugging%20VBS%20enclaves
I managed to correctly compile and sign the enclave, and I'm able to run it. The problem is, even after following the steps in the article I linked, I can't debug the code running inside the enclave.
I take the following steps:

Debug the enclave host process using Windbg
Set a breakpoint after loading and initializing the enclave
Reload the symbols by running ".reload -f vbsenclave.dll"
Set a breakpoint inside the enclave
Continue running

After performing these steps and continuing, I get the following errors:
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
Unable to get program counter
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
(177c.1d8c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n87
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
Unable to get program counter
No flat address for current instruction
 ??              ???
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n87
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n87
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n87
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057
GetContextState failed, 0x80070057

The code of the enclave and host app I'm using are from Microsoft's example enclave here: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/VbsEnclave
the enclave is created with the debuggable flag:
const IMAGE_ENCLAVE_CONFIG __enclave_config = {
    sizeof(IMAGE_ENCLAVE_CONFIG),
    IMAGE_ENCLAVE_MINIMUM_CONFIG_SIZE,
    IMAGE_ENCLAVE_POLICY_DEBUGGABLE,    // DO NOT SHIP DEBUGGABLE ENCLAVES TO PRODUCTION
    0,
    0,
    0,
    { 0xFE, 0xFE },    // family id
    { 0x01, 0x01 },    // image id
    0,                 // version
    0,                 // SVN
    0x10000000,        // size
    16,                // number of threads
    IMAGE_ENCLAVE_FLAG_PRIMARY_IMAGE
};


The host app also loads the enclave with the debuggable flag:
    // Create the enclave
    constexpr ENCLAVE_CREATE_INFO_VBS CreateInfo
    {
        ENCLAVE_VBS_FLAG_DEBUG, // Flags
        { 0x10, 0x20, 0x30, 0x40, 0x41, 0x31, 0x21, 0x11 }, // OwnerID
    };

This error only occurs when attempting to debug the enclave, it works fine as expected without a debugger.
Anyone encountered this problem or have any idea what might be causing it?
Thanks!

Please add the code that creates the enclave. As explained in the link you provided, you need to explicitly enable debugging.

Managed to solve this - I tried to perform the debugging inside an Hyper-V VM, when I switched to a VMWare VM this problem was solved.
